# Convert a string to a date in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I'm reading text from a flat file in c# and need to test whether certain values are dates. They could be in either YYYYMMDD format or MM/DD/YY format. What is the simplest way to do this in .Net?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```cs
string[] formats = {"yyyyMMdd", "MM/dd/yy"};
var Result = DateTime.ParseExact(input, formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

or

```cs
DateTime result;
string[] formats = {"yyyyMMdd", "MM/dd/yy"};
DateTime.TryParseExact(input, formats, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
```

More info in the MSDN documentation on [ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact) and [TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact).

Comment: This is better than mine. Didn't know you could do a string array for formats. Very nice!

Comment: Even better! Just what I needed.

Comment: Make sure you check the return value of DateTime.TryParseExact(...) as that will be the only way you can tell if it succeeded or not.

Answer (score 4):

[DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) method

Comment: Since I can't edit your answer, I thought it might help to provide a link to the MSDN article for that method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx

Comment: [@Yadyn]: i figured the intellisense would be enough, but ok i added the link to be thorough - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you could try also  TryParseExact for set exact format.
method, here's documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx

e.g.

```
DateTime outDt;
bool blnYYYMMDD = 
     DateTime.TryParseExact(yourString,"yyyyMMdd"
                            ,CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,DateTimeStyles.None
                            , out outDt);
```

I hope i help you.

Comment: Dude!  That is so useful, I lost nearly an hour over this, even though I know I've done it before somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do Convert.ToDateTime

not sure the advantages of either

Answer (score 0):

Using TryParse will not throw an exception if it fails.  Also, TryParse will return True/False, indicating the success of the conversion.

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TryParse method to check validity and parse at same time.

```
DateTime output;
string input = "09/23/2008";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input,"MM/dd/yy", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out output) || DateTime.TryParseExact(input,"yyyyMMdd", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out output))
{
    //handle valid date
}
else
{
    //handle invalid date
}
```