# How to convert DateTime object to dd/mm/yyyy in C#?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Convert a string to a date in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123263/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-net)
>   [format date in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501460/format-date-in-c)
>   [What markup is used to format StackOverflow questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808057/what-markup-is-used-to-format-stackoverflow-questions)

How to convert DateTime object to dd/mm/yyyy in C#?

Answer (score 46):

One thing to note in addition to the other answers - / is a format character itself, representing the local date separator. If you want to make *absolutely* sure it uses an actual slash, either use the invariant culture (which uses a slash):

```
string s = dateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or escape the slashes:

```
string s = dateTime.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy");
```

Comment: I will give Jon credit, that is something I have seen alot, but never considered.

Comment: or `String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", dateTime);` if that's more suited (to save the next person looking it up)

Comment: thanks.. it worked :)

Answer (score 33):

Are you talking about converting to a string for printing or something?

```
String s = DateTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

And to be complete, here is more information about [DateTime.ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf.aspx) and [DateTime formatting in general](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.aspx).

Comment: Handy list of string format codes: http://john-sheehan.com/blog/net-cheat-sheets/ /shameless_self_promo

Comment: or ToString capital T :)

Comment: Right, right. Damn C# casing always gets me.

Comment: I had to double check to see if the question was Java.

Comment: Actually, this code has a subtle bug in it. The forward slash appears to be a special character referring to the locale's default delimiter. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6343332/122764 -- escape the slash in quotes: ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy")

Answer (score 18):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
string s = d.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```