# Converting DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert DateTime object to dd/mm/yyyy in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941502/how-to-convert-datetime-object-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-c)

I'm new to c# and was hoping someone could help me clean up some code.

I have the following method which converts a DateTime to a custom Event string e.g. `30th of Jan 2012` is converted to `201201` (ignores the day)

```
public ConvertToEventDate(DateTime date)
{   
    var year = date.Year.ToString();
    var month = date.Month.ToString();
    month = month.Length == 2 ? month : "0" + month;
    return year + month;
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this conversion.

Comment: The above will not compile - there is no return type defined in the function signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do this;

```
public string ConvertToEventDate(DateTime date)
{   
    return date.ToString("yyyyMM");
}
```

you can also put this into an Extension method like this;

```
public static class ExtenstionMethods
{
    public static string ToEventDate(this DateTime date)
    {
        return date.ToString("yyyyMM");
    }
}
```

and then call it ike this;

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(2012, 30, 1);

    date.ToEventDate();
```

as opposed to this;

```
ConvertToEventDate(date);
```

Comment: I like the extension method idea, because it's being called from all over the code so prefer to keep it centralised

Answer (score 2):

```
public string ConvertToEventDate(DateTime date)
{ 
    return date.ToString("yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Have a look at the [custom formatting strings docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: I don't like the edit above, I don't see the point of putting this in a function. simply MyDateTimeObject.ToString("yyyyMM") is easier to read, encapsulating this in a new function adds nothing imo.

Comment: It is in a function because the OP put it in a function.

Comment: The OP asked for cleaner code. I think it is cleaner and clearer to call date.ToString("yyyyMM") than to call ConvertToEventDate(date).

Comment: Nothing stops you from editing back. But at least conserve the _correct_ casing.

Comment: Thinking about it, I guess putting it in a function allows the event date format to be changed more easily in the future. So I see where you are coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Others have suggested `ToString("yyyyMM")` which is *basically* there - but I would *suggest* you probably want to specify the invariant culture. Otherwise if the thread's current culture uses a non-Gregorian calendar, you could end up with a month/year you're not expecting. So I'd use:

```
string text = date.ToString("yyyyMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

See the documentation for [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for more information if you want to change the exact format later.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return date.ToString("yyyyMM");
```

Comment: `Format`? Do you mean `ToString`?