# ASP.NET DisplayFormat dd/MM/yyyy didn't work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date-format

My model

```
[Display(Name = "Tanggal Lahir")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime TanggalLahir { get; set; }
```

My view

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TanggalLahir)
```

but its still display format data with MM/dd/yyyy.

even my web.config

```
<system.web>
  <globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB"/>
  <authentication mode="None" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="30000000" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1):

declare your property as string

```
[Display(Name = "Tanggal Lahir")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
public string TanggalLahir { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.TanggalLahir, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new {maxlength = 10})
```

you can try something like that..

Answer (score 0):

1f you can't get it working on the model you could try it on the view.

```
 @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TanggalLahir, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new {maxlength = 10})
```

(or)

```
  @Html.EditorFor(m => m.TanggalLahir, new { @Value = Model.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") })
```

Comment: if i remove it, input field doesn't show date picker dropdown :(

Comment: Here is correct format  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

Comment: i'm sorry, still didn't works >_< i think the problem in somewhere else maybe :/

Comment: Can you change it to DataFormatString = "{0:d}"

Comment: its like [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941502/how-to-convert-datetime-object-to-dd-mm-yyyy-in-c), there are some useful info which might help you. Also make sure that you specify the CultureInfo as Invariant Culture.