# How to get datagridview date column as ddMMyyyy

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hi i set the datasource of a datagridview to my sql statement which selects the date from a table in database, on the gridview itself it shows just fine as dd/mm/yyyy but when i get the value from the datagridview cell and convert it to string it becomes dd/MM/yyyy 12am, how do i remove the time??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a string to a date in .net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123263/convert-a-string-to-a-date-in-net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;       
var date = dateAndTime.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ToString() property. And pass it the format you want as a string. 
For example:

```
var today = DateTime.Now();
var formattedDate = today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

This will solve your problem, in this way you can use the format that you want.